# split foreach loop based on some column value

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have a table with a column name type,how can i show results based on its column values in one query ?

```
Tags
id|name|type    //type can be fixed,price

Tag::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Now i want to show price and fixed in two different partials.what is the best way to do.

I can do this by the following query,but i am looking for the best approach,probably with once query.

```
Tag::where('type','fixed')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
Tag::where('type','price')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your query should be like this:

```
$tags = Tag::orderBy('id', 'desc')->groupBy('type')->get();
```

and your foreach loop should look like this:

```
    @foreach ($tags as $tag) 
        @if($tag->fixed)
            // do smth
        @else 
             //do smth

        @endif
   @endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,i was missing group by clause.

Answer (score 2):

I might have the wrong end of the stick, you could mean that you want to do the logic within your controller and return a different view depending on the outcome, but, I would return everything in one query as you have already done

`Tag::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();`

The `@include` blade directive contains an additional argument which is the data that you pass to this partial:

`@include('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])`

More information on the @include directive can be found in the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#including-sub-views)